# problem with jquery move image

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can get x,y when mousedown in image and then mouse move in the image and then mouseup get x,y

(2 x,y 1-x,y when mouse down 2-x,y when mouse up)
all the event in the one image.
and language jquery

this my code by this not working(image stick to mouse and only mouse_d called)

var mx1;
var my1;

$("document").ready(function ()
{
    $("img#ground").bind("mousedown",mouse_d);
    $("img#ground").bind("mouseup",mouse_u);
    $("img#ground").bind("dragstart",mouse_d);
});

```
      function mouse_d(event)
      {    

            mx1=event.pageX;
            my1=event.pageY;
      }

    function mouse_u(e)
    {

            mx2=e.pageX;
            my2=e.pageY;
            mx2=mx1-mx2;
            my2=my1-my2;
        }
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery anywhere in your code, so why did you tag the question as such?

Comment: i want convert this code to jquery

Comment: var mx1;
var my1;

$("document").ready(function ()
{
    $("img#ground").bind("mousedown",mouse_d);
    $("img#ground").bind("mouseup",mouse_u);
});

          function mouse_d(event)
          {    
                mx1=event.pageX;
                my1=event.pageY;}

Comment: but image stick to mouse and drag,how can fix image.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to achieve a drag and drop effect?

if so this is the ultimate solution:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

when using firefox is the isNS variable true? otherwise an mouseup event isn't set.

Comment: i dont want move image , i want catch x,y when click down and when mouse up.